# Possible to highlight hard-coded string literals and navigate between them?

Tags: android, intellij-idea

I can see that IDEA 13 marks if a string is hard-coded string literal. But the default highlight can be easily missed after you get tired of investigating the long class, and I found no way to automatically navigate between them, so all the work has to be done manually which is very error prone as time passes.

Is there a way to highlight all hard-coded string literals like it does when we search for files?

And can we navigate withing them, again like we can during search?

Comment: Check out the Lint it marks hardcoded strings as warnings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Main menu - Analyze - inspect code
Then wait until analyze will be completed.
At the bottom menu "Inspection" choose:
Android - Android Lint - Harcoded Text - double click on line